# ASP Classic - Include VBScript page in a JavaScript page?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, jscript

Is there a way to include a VBScript page into an ASP page written using Javascript?

There is an ASP page written in Javascript, but our sidebar menu is written in VBScript.  When I include the sidebar asp file into the Javascript the server gives an error.

< %@ LANGUAGE="JavaScript" %>

<%

...

< !--#include file="sidebar.asp"-->

...

where sidebar.asp is written using VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but my guess is that the sidebar.asp will be executed before your Javascript code.

```
< %@ LANGUAGE="JavaScript" %>

<%

...
<script language="VBscript" runat=server> 
< !--#include file="sidebar.asp"-->
</script> 
...
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The first error I got was that I had to use the src attribute of the script tag. When I put the sidebar.asp as the src, then I got errors on the ASP content (the <% ).

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time, but I write my ASP/JScript pages a bit differently. Instead of switching the page language to "JavaScript", I leave it at the default "VBScript" and then use a `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" RUNAT="Server">` block for my JScript code. The JavaScript `SCRIPT` blocks are executed before the normal `<% %>` tags, so I do all my page processing in the `SCRIPT` blocks and then simply plug the results into the page with `<% %>` tags. Here's an example:

mainpage.asp:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" RUNAT="Server">
var name;
var address;
var phone;
function main() {
    var rec = go_to_database();
    name = rec.first_name + " " + rec.last_name;
    address = rec.address;
    phone = rec.phone;
}
</SCRIPT><% main() %>
<html><head><title><%= name %></title></head><body>
<p>Name: <%= name %><br/>
Address: <%= address %><br/>
Phone Number: <%= phone %></p>
<!--#include file="subpage.asp"-->
</body></html>
```

subpage.asp:

```
<p>Blah blah blah, some random VBScript code: <%
    Dim whatever
    whatever = some_silly_thing()
    Response.Write(whatever)
%>.</p>
```

So, first IIS processes the SSI and includes `subpage.asp` into `mainpage.asp`. Then, it evaluates the JScript `SCRIPT` block, declaring the variables `name`, `address`, and `phone` and defining the function `main`.

Then it evaluates each `<% %>` tag in order. `<% main() %>` call the `main` function and sets values for `name`, `address`, and `phone`. Then `<%= name %>`, `<%= address %>`, and `<%= phone %>` substitute those values into the page. Finally, the `<% %>` code from `subpage.asp` is evaluated and the `Response.Write` value ends up in the page output.

While the whole page is not written in JScript, the vast majority of the code can be, inside the `SCRIPT` block. Would that work for you?

Comment: This is the best approach I've seen.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know anyone was still writing Classic ASP!

Comment: Yup there's still a bit of legacy stuff out there. "If it ain't broken".